# Foreign constraint On Delete Cascade not working

Tags: mysql, magento, constraints

I have a custom table created which has a foreign constraint on the `core_website` table.  However, the `on delete cascade` isn't working.

I did a search and found this [relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320236/in-mysql-on-delete-cascade-not-working), which notes that the data types between the two columns have to be the same.  Both data types are `smallint(5)`.

I did notice one minor discrepancy in the column definition, which is that in core_website, Allow Null is *not* set, and Default is not set to zero, whereas in the account table, Allow Null *is* set and Default is zero.  I didn't think changing these would have any effect, but I went ahead and changed them on the account table to match, but that didn't help.

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `account_id` smallint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `code` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `FK_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: So, if you delete row from `core_website` table related rows in `account` table aren't deleted, right?

Comment: Actually other way around, I'm deleting from the account table and wanting the core_website record deleted.

Comment: In this case you need add foreign key to `core_website` table and point it to `website_id` field in `account` table. In other words, foreign key should be added to dependent table and pointed to main table, in this case when you delete row from main table - row from dependent table will be deleted because of FK. In your case you did it "upside down".

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  You should post your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add foreign key to `core_website` table and point it to `website_id` field in `account` table. In other words, foreign key should be added to the dependent table and pointed to main table, in this case when you delete row from main table - row from dependent table will be deleted because of FK. In your case you did it "upside down".

Answer (score 1):

try this and let us the result pls.

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `account_id` smallint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `code` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `FK_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Hi Oguz, so the only difference being that "PRIMARY KEY" is included in-line with the account_id field definition, as opposed to on a separate line?

Comment: yes, mysql ignores inline foreign key constraints, so you should explicitly define.

Comment: Thanks Oguz, I think I remember reading a thread where an inline foreign key constraint was an issue.  But actually I don't think my foreign key constraint is inline, right?  You were suggesting that I make my PRIMARY KEY definition inline, but my primary key is also working just fine.

Looks like @zyava had the answer, I was a little confused about which direction foreign constraints work.

Thanks for your help though!