# On delete cascade not deleting the associates entries

Tags: mysql

I have a `marks` table which holds the foreign key to an associates message. I used `ON DELETE` with the expectation that deleting an entry in the `marks` table would also delete the associated message. It is not working as expected though. [I checked out all the other post and can't find any relevant to this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320236/in-mysql-on-delete-cascade-not-working)

I can insert into the database successfully

```
DELETE FROM marks WHERE x = 37.7836
```

but when I delete a mark the message that is associated with it is not deleted. Any insights as to what I am doing wrong here?

Edit:
Here is an image of me demonstrating my deletion process:
[image]

**schema**

```
DROP DATABASE uncovery;
CREATE DATABASE uncovery;

SET foreign_key_checks=0;

USE uncovery;

CREATE TABLE marks (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  x float(10, 6),
  y float(10, 6),
  z float(10, 6),
  timestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  messageId int(5),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId)
    REFERENCES messages(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  messageString text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**EDIT 2: Schema Refactor**

Here is my newly updated schema:
[image]

As you can see I am getting an error that this is invalid when I try to run it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key as you've created it won't work the way you expect. Under your schema, if an entry is deleted from `messages`, it will delete all corresponding entries from the `marks` table, not the other way around.

Also, you must ensure that you are using the `InnoDB` storage engine for your tables, or your foreign keys won't work at all. They are not supported in the `MyISAM` engine type.

To get your schema working such that deleting a mark will cause a message to be deleted, you need to have a `markId` as a foreign key in the messages table, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `messageString` text,
  `markId` int(5) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `markId` (`markId`),
  CONSTRAINT `messages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`markId`) REFERENCES `marks` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `marks` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `x` float(10,6) default NULL,
  `y` float(10,6) default NULL,
  `z` float(10,6) default NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I am using InnoDB. How do I change my schema so deleting a mark will cause a message to be deleted?

Comment: I have edited my question to include information about what happens when I try your suggested answer. Thanks!

Comment: Oops don't forget the closing ; on each create table statement. Also you appear to be using single quotes ' instead of backticks ` on your table and column names.

Comment: Whats the difference between single quotes and backticks? I never used backticks in MySQL before.

Comment: Backticks just allow your table or column names to include MySQL's reserved words. If you aren't going to use any reserved words, you don't need to use backticks, but there is no harm in using them. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html