# Foreign Key accepted but not working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm creating a 'polls' plugin for my website, and for this I have 2x tables (shown below).

What I'm trying to achieve is that by delete a 'poll' from the `dd_polls` table, any linked foreign keys on the `dd_poll_options` table are also deleted.

Both tables create just fine, but my expectation as mentioned above is not happening.

Am I using `foreign keys` in the correct way, and if so, how can my code be fixed? Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE dd_polls (
    ID smallint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    poll_created_by smallint(3) DEFAULT "0",
    poll_created_date datetime DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00" NOT NULL,
    poll_last_edited_by smallint(3) DEFAULT "0",
    poll_last_edited_date datetime DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00" NOT NULL,
    poll_title varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    poll_start_date date DEFAULT "0000-00-00" NOT NULL,
    poll_expiry_date date DEFAULT "0000-00-00" NOT NULL,
    poll_closed tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    poll_allow_recasting tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    poll_show_votes tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE dd_poll_options (
    ID smallint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    option_text text(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    option_order smallint(2) DEFAULT "0",
    poll_id smallint(3) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (poll_id) REFERENCES dd_polls (ID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (ID)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but I think you need to use the InnoDB engine for this to work. I bet you are using MyISAM.

Here is another question with the same symptoms: [on-delete-cascade-not-working-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308255/on-delete-cascade-not-working-in-mysql)

And isn't the correct syntax

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (poll_id) REFERENCES dd_polls(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

?

Comment: `CONSTRAINT` is optional but I agree on the rest, it's probably MyISAM.

Comment: The type is indeed `MyISAM` on those two tables. I'll look for a way of creating them as InnoDB and try again. Thanks.

Comment: @David: also look at the link I posted in my answer. There is an easy way to switch the storage engine to InnoDB per table on the fly: ALTER TABLE xxxx ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: @mwhs - Thank you so much. `ALTER TABLE xxxx ENGINE = InnoDB` worked like a charm and now when I delete a poll, the options linked to it in another table are deleted. Thanks also for the link, I'll be sure to create tables using the `InnoDB` engine in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE `dd_polls` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `poll_id`, `id` ) 
REFERENCES `dd_poll_options` ( `poll_id`, `id`) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```